# Store input file name (const *file*) to a char array

Tags: c

So I am trying to take a text file (e.g.`file.txt`) as function argument and to save the file name as a char array. I wrote this simple code below and expected `FnameToChar("test.txt")`would return a char array as `array[]={'t', 'e', 's', 't', '\0'}`. How should I fix the syntax to make it work?

```
char FnameToChar(const char *fn)
{
    char filename[20];
    filename = fn;
    return filename;
}
```

Comment: Your input is already a char array, so the function is not needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The return type should be `char*`, not `char`.
- You should use [`strcpy()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) to copy strings.
- Non-static local variable will be invalidated on returning from functions. You should allocate an array dynamically.

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* for malloc() */
#include <string.h> /* for strlen() and strcpy() */

char* FnameToChar(const char *fn)
{
    char* filename = malloc(strlen(fn) + 1); /* +1 for terminating null-character */
    if (filename == NULL) return NULL;
    strcpy(filename, fn);
    return filename;
}
```

Of [`strdup()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html) is convenient if it is supported in your environment:

```
char* FnameToChar(const char *fn)
{
    return strdup(fn);
}
```

Returning a pointer to static array is another choice, but be careful not to cause buffer overrun and note that this is not thread-safe:

```
#include <string.h> /* for strncpy() */

char* FnameToChar(const char *fn)
{
    static char filename[20];
    strncpy(filename, fn, sizeof(filename));
    filename[sizeof(filename) - 1] = '\0'; /* make sure to have terminating null-character */
    return filename;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you need to NULL check fn?

Answer (score 1):

You have several problems with your code:

1. You cannot return an array from a function in c. What you can do instead is return a pointer. Please note that you will have to allocate memory on the heap in order to achieve your goal, you cannot return an address of a local variable.
2. Your return value is all wrong. You should return a `char *` and not `char`, which is a single character.
3. You cannot copy a c-string with the `assignment operator`. You need to use a function like `strcpy`. In your case, perhapse you should use `strdup` which creates a new copy of your string, just remember you would have to `free` it.